# Saving a toogle switch value in Django

Tags: javascript, django, onclick, toggleswitch

Hi I am just trying to save a toggle switch value onclick to save to a Boolean field in Django

home.html

```
<style>
    .home-container{
display:grid;
grid-template-columns: 1fr 4fr;
}

.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
}

.switch input { 
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked + .slider {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

input:focus + .slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}

/* Rounded sliders */
.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
} 
    
</style>


   <div>
      <label class="switch">
 ** <input type="checkbox" checked>**
  <span class="slider round"></span>
</label>
    </div>
```

models.py

```
is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

urls.py

```
path('engine/', views.engine, name="engine"),
```

I tried several suggestions on the web but could not make it work as I am new to development.
I know I need to use javascript. Please help write my views.py and javascript in home.html.

Comment: Provide javascript code & view which is responsible for updating your `is_active` flag

Comment: I am not sure what js to use. I am hoping someone can share an example of how to save a toggle button on click in django.